Extra Space present between TextInput and InternalTextInput in React Native
enter image description here
I am creating a login form using react native and there is a slight space visible between the TextInput and the InternalTextInput (As I could see in the Element Inspector) Due to this the dropdown and TextInput are not aligned.
<View
    style={{
        flexDirection: "row",
        marginLeft: marginLeftRight,
        marginTop: 15,
        marginRight: marginLeftRight,
        justifyContent: "space-between",
    }}
>
    <Dropdown
        style={[styles.dropdown]}
        data={allCountries}
        labelField="code"
        valueField="id"
        itemTextStyle={[TextStyles.Paragraph, textStyle]}
        selectedTextStyle={[TextStyles.Paragraph, textStyle]}
        placeholder="Country"
        placeholderStyle={[TextStyles.Paragraph, textStyle]}
        search
        itemContainerStyle={[
            containerStyle,
            styles.columnFlex,
            { flex: 1, justifyContent: "center" },
        ]}
        onChange={(item) => {
            console.log("Item select: ", item);
            setCountry(item);
        }}
        confirmSelectItem
        inputSearchStyle={[TextStyles.Paragraph, textStyle]}
        //containerStyle={[containerStyle, styles.rowFlex, {borderColor: 'lavander'}]}
    />
    <TextInput
        keyboardType={"number-pad"}
        style={[{
            flexDirection: "row",
            flex: 1,
            height: 40,
            borderWidth: 0.2,
            marginLeft: 10,
            paddingTop:0
            
        },]}
        contentStyle={{paddingTop: 0, marginTop: 0}}
        autoComplete="cc-number"
        mode="outlined"
        label="Phone"
        onChangeText={(text) => setMobileNumber(text.trim())}
        error={mobileNumberError}
        value={mobileNumber}
    />
</View>

I used the above code
